# Correct usage of Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, pnp-powershell

A SPD workflow has become suspended, but I'm unable to cancel it. I'm trying to kill the workflow with the PNP command, but thats not working either, Am I missing something?

I'm using:-

```
Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance -identity e31bd8e7-90f3-42a3-898b-e9ebd326befc -force -verbose
```

The response I get in powershell is

```
VERBOSE: Instance object not set. Looking up site workflows by GUID: e31bd8e7-90f3-42a3-898b-e9ebd326befc
```

The workflow is still stuck in suspended mode, I'm unable to kill it. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try my edited reply ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo to stop workflow instance using PnP PowerShell.
Get a running workflow instance and then stop it:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"


Get-PnPWorkflowInstance -List "DateTest" -ListItem 2 | Where-Object {($_.Id -eq "21870821-2e70-4c29-bca9-b07eef8e53b5")} |
        Foreach-Object {
            Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance -Identity $_ -Verbose -Force 
        }
```

The Id in the code snippet above can be found in the workflow url:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get this error message:- Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
'SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PipeBinds.WorkflowInstancePipeBind' required by parameter 'Identity'.
Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:36
+ Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance -identity $wfinstance
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Workflows.StopWorkflowInstance

Comment: This could be because the Get-PNPWorkflowInstance returns multiple workflows that have already completed as well as the workflow that is suspended

Comment: @Akashic, If you have multiple started workflows in specific item, please use Foreach-Object to loop and get the specific workflow instance with Id

Answer (score 0):

The [Stop-PnPWorkflowInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/stop-pnpworkflowinstance?view=sharepoint-ps) accepts -identity param as the workflow instance object. You can use [Get-PnPWorkflowInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpworkflowinstance?view=sharepoint-ps) command to get the instance and supply it to the stop workflow command.

Comment: Can you provide an example, this is just info from the documentation.